# Oracle query not filtering the expected result

Tags: asp.net, oracle

I have a debugged query, In which I add a condition like

```
AND cp.area = 'Like upper(%Aarey%)'
```

For **Aarey** the result exist in the database, but it does not fetch any records.

Below is my debugged query

```
SELECT   CASE type_of_channel_p
        WHEN '10'
           THEN 'Broker'
        WHEN '30'
           THEN 'International Property Consultant'
     END type_of_cp,
     CASE cp.type_of_firm
        WHEN '10'
           THEN 'Asset Consultant'
        WHEN '20'
           THEN 'Estate Consultant'
        WHEN '30'
           THEN 'Broker'
        WHEN '40'
           THEN 'Housing Agency'
        WHEN '50'
           THEN 'Partnership Firm'
        WHEN '60'
           THEN 'Property consultant'
        WHEN '70'
           THEN 'Sole selling broker'
        WHEN '80'
           THEN 'International Property Consultant'
     END type_of_firm,
     CASE
        WHEN ld.broker_id > 0
           THEN 'Broker'
        ELSE 'New'
     END cp_type, rating,
     TO_CHAR (cp.creation_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') entry_date, cp.mkey,
     TO_CHAR (cp.date_of_introduction, 'dd/mm/yyyy') date_of_introduction,
     cp.name_of_firm, cp.pan_no, cp.service_tax_no,
        cp.address1
     || ' '
     || cp.address2
     || ' '
     || cs.city
     || ' ' || cp.pin_code
     || ' '
     || cs.state
     || ' '
     || cs.country_name address,
     a.area, ct.city, st.state, cn.country_name country, cp.person_name,
     cp.mobile, cp.landline, cp.email_id, ev.description created_by,
     ev1.description introduced_by, cp.remarks remarks,
     cp.remarks remarks1, fm.sr_no, fm.sr_no followup_srno,
     fm.follow_up_type, fm.activity_description,
     TO_CHAR (fm.next_follow_up_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') next_follow_up_date,
     fm.next_to_do_activity next_activity, fm.commen comments,
     fm.commen comments1,
     TO_CHAR (cp.rating_update_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') rating_update_date,
     cm.meeting_name
FROM xxcus.xxacl_pn_new_cha_part cp,
     xxcus.xxacl_pn_type_of_firm_v tf,
     (SELECT DISTINCT broker_id
                 FROM xxcus.xxacl_pn_lease_det ld
                WHERE ld.sr_no = 1
                  AND broker_flag = 'C'
                  AND ld.broker_id > 0) ld,
     xxcus.xxacl_pn_city_state_v cs,
     apps.fnd_user ev,
     apps.fnd_user ev1,
     xxcus.xxacl_pn_ncp_followup_max_v fm,
     xxcus.xxacl_pn_city_area_v a,
     xxcus.xxacl_pn_city_v ct,
     xxcus.xxacl_pn_state_v st,
     xxcus.xxacl_pn_country_v cn,
     xxcus.xxacl_pn_cp_meeting_v cm WHERE cp.delete_flag = 'N'
 AND cp.mkey = fm.mkey(+)
 AND cp.type_of_firm = tf.firm_id(+)
 AND cp.broker_id = ld.broker_id(+)
 AND cp.city = cs.city_code(+)
 AND cp.created_by = ev.user_id
 AND cp.introduced_by = ev1.user_id
 AND cp.area = a.area_code(+)
 AND ct.city_code(+) = cp.city
 AND st.state_code(+) = cp.state
 AND cp.cp_meeting = cm.meeting_code(+)
 AND cn.country_id(+) = cp.country
 AND cp.area = 'Like upper(%Aarey%)' ORDER BY cp.creation_date DESC,
     ev.description,
     cp.date_of_introduction,
     fm.next_follow_up_date
```

Kindly suggest what is wrong with the query, is my condition is not executed properly or something else?

Comment: You want to check if cp.area contains this string: 'Like upper(%Aarey%) or you want to use like - cp.area LIKE upper(%Aarey%)

Comment: @Yossi: i guess i need second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you condition seems wrong..

Try something like this if you want to check if cp.area contains string AAREY

```
AND cp.area LIKE '%AAREY%'
```

Or if its a column, then do it with concat:

```
AND cp.area LIKE concat('%',upper(Aarey),'%')
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe
    AND cp.area = 'Like upper(%Aarey%)'

should be `upper(cp.area) like '%AAREY%'